# Rebinding message from thousand of archives in sencha gxt

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, ant, gxt

Whenever I am trying to build my project using **Ant Build**, it gives me thousands of Rebinding warning in **sencha gxt 3.x,**
Although the build gets successful but it takes too much time which is unbearable.
one of the warning is here as an example

[java]          Rebinding com.sencha.gxt.theme.base.client.widget.CollapsePanelDefaultAppearance.CollapsePanelResources
[java]             Checking rule

One more thing to notice, this issue was not present when i was using **gwt 2.x**.

**strong text**Can someone help me out

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because GXT 3 uses an appearance pattern. Normally an apperance has a related html- and css-file, which is created and optimized by GWT generators. Also, it makes it quite easy to change an appearnace.

Have you tried to set the logLevel to ERROR?